# Using Shapely methods (explain_validity and make_valid) on shapefile

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, geodataframe

I'm trying to find and repair invalidity in my polygons. I have already found out that 10 polygons have self-intersection problems in QGIS, trying the same thing with shapely.

This is my code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.validation import explain_validity

data = gpd.read_file('land.shp')
explain_validity(data)
```

Return an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [89], in <module>
      3 data=gpd.read_file('land.shp')
      4 data
----> 5 explain_validity(data)

File ~\.conda\envs\geopandas_env\lib\site-packages\shapely\validation.py:26, in explain_validity(ob)
      8 def explain_validity(ob):
      9     """
     10     Explain the validity of the input geometry, if it is invalid.
     11     This will describe why the geometry is invalid, and might
   (...)
     24 
     25     """
---> 26     return lgeos.GEOSisValidReason(ob._geom)

File ~\.conda\envs\geopandas_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5583, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5576 if (
   5577     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5578     and name not in self._metadata
   5579     and name not in self._accessors
   5580     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5581 ):
   5582     return self[name]
-> 5583 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

The name of geometry column is 'geometry'. What is wrong?
Is it possible to get results like this:

```
   id       geometry                             explain_validity
0   1  MULTILINESTRING ((98573.148 61104...  Ring Self-intersection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two above method (`explain_validity` and `make_valid`) are applicable not to the shapefile itself, but to the objects (geometries of features) that it contains.

To apply the [`explain_validity()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#validation) method:

> Returns a string explaining the validity or invalidity of the object.
>
> The messages may or may not have a representation of a problem point
> that can be parsed out.

one can use the following code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.validation import explain_validity

absolute_path_to_file = 'P:/Test/qgis_test/lines_test.shp'

shp = gpd.read_file(absolute_path_to_file)

shp['validity'] = shp.apply(lambda row: explain_validity(row.geometry), axis=1)

print(shp)
```

that will give this:

```
   id                                           geometry        validity
0   1  MULTILINESTRING ((98573.148 6110418.666, 40758...  Valid Geometry
```

Making use of the [`make_valid()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#validation.make_valid) method

> Returns a valid representation of the geometry, if it is invalid. If
> it is valid, the input geometry will be returned.
>
> In many cases, in order to create a valid geometry, the input geometry
> must be split into multiple parts or multiple geometries. If the
> geometry must be split into multiple parts of the same geometry type,
> then a multi-part geometry (e.g. a MultiPolygon) will be returned. if
> the geometry must be split into multiple parts of different types,
> then a GeometryCollection will be returned.

is useful together with the [`is_valid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.is_valid) method:

> The validity test is meaningful only for *Polygons* and *MultiPolygons*.
> `True` is always returned for other types of geometries.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.validation import make_valid

absolute_path_to_file = 'P:/Test/qgis_test/lines_test.shp'

shp = gpd.read_file(absolute_path_to_file)

shp.geometry = shp.apply(lambda row: make_valid(row.geometry) if not row.geometry.is_valid else row.geometry, axis=1)

print(shp)
```

That will return this:

```
   id                                           geometry
0   1  MULTILINESTRING ((98573.148 6110418.666, 40758...
```

To include the validity check for other geometry types, one can combine both method (`explain_validity` and `make_valid`) in one line:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.validation import make_valid, explain_validity

absolute_path_to_file = 'P:/Test/qgis_test/lines_test.shp'

shp = gpd.read_file(absolute_path_to_file)

shp.geometry = shp.apply(lambda row: make_valid(row.geometry) if not explain_validity(row) == 'Valid Geometry' else row.geometry, axis=1)

print(shp)
```

It returns the following:

```
   id                                           geometry
0   1  MULTILINESTRING ((98573.148 6110418.666, 40758...
```

---

**References:**

- [Shapely "is_valid" returns True to invalid overlap polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042379/shapely-is-valid-returns-true-to-invalid-overlap-polygons)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. Just to confirm, there is no way to iterate every geometry/row and then apply the method explain_validity? Because I want the result like this:  Ring Self-intersection [1 1].

Comment: Did you try the code I provided ? I do not understand what do you exactly means with *"way to iterate every geometry/row and then apply the method explain_validity"*.

Comment: The question is edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to control the validity of every geometry in the shapefile (= row in the geodataframe)

```
 for i in data.index:
      explain_validity(data.geometry[i])
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Any other suggestions?